# How to find Novartis medicines in openFDA drug labelling data

Tags: openfda, drugs

I am trying to look at the Novartis medicines on openFDA open data on drug labeling for a given period.

I tried this:

```
https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=spl_patient_package_insert:"Novartis"& spl_product_data_elements&effective_time:[20110601+TO+20181231]&limit=1
```

But I end up getting an error:

```
{
    "error": {
    "code": "BAD_REQUEST",
    "message": "Invalid parameter:  spl_product_data_elements"
  }
}
```

What am doing wrong? What is the correct field to get Novartis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the corrected query:

```
https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=spl_patient_package_insert:"Novartis"+AND+_exists_:spl_product_data_elements+AND+effective_time:[20110601+TO+20181231]&limit=1
```

You need to use `+AND+` instead of `&` and `_exists_` to ensure a particular field is present in the document. More information about the syntax of openFDA queries can be found [on our website](https://open.fda.gov/apis/query-syntax/).